# watch depth and content of complex object hierarchy in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to write some code to detect changes to a complex nested, hierarchical object in angular.  I was hoping that a `$watch` or `$watchCollection` expression would suffice, however this is proving difficult to achieve.

Could someone suggest  a good approach to the problem?

an example of the data structure I am looking to watch is (in json):

```
{
    "$type":"<>f__AnonymousType7`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], VM.ConfigurationServer",
    "Name":"DevelopmentEnvironment",
    "Descendents":{
        "$type":"<>f__AnonymousType7`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]][], VM.ConfigurationServer",
        "$values":[{
            "$type":"<>f__AnonymousType7`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], VM.ConfigurationServer",
            "Name":"MoreSpecificEnvironment",
            "Descendents":{
                "$type":"<>f__AnonymousType7`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]][], VM.ConfigurationServer",
                "$values":[{
                    "$type":"<>f__AnonymousType7`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]], VM.ConfigurationServer",
                    "Name":"level3",
                    "Descendents":null
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

as you can see the TypeNameHandling of the Json Serializer is set to All, that is necessary for other parts of the system.

What I need to be made aware of is any changes to the `Name` property on any of the nested objects, and also addition or removal of a `Descendent`.

I have tried both

`scope.$watch(<objectname>, function(){...}, true);` and

`scope.watchCollection(<objectname>, function(){...}, true);`

both of which detect changes to the Top level `Name` and `Descendents` properties but nothing on objects nested further.

Based on my understanding, this suggests to me that the `angular.equals` function is not noticing the changes below the top level.

Is there a way to inject a custom equality comparer?

Is there a way to change the `watchExpression` dynamically?  Thus applying a watch to every object in the hierarchy, and as the hierarchy changes changing the `watchExpression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `angular.equals()` ignores keys starting with a `$` sign, i.e. in your case `$type` and `$values` are ignored during comparison.

**Do not use properties starting with $ signs in your Angular code apart from Angulars own services / directives / etc.!**

[Check out this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/030wxg9b/1/) and try renaming the `$values` array to just `values`.

Comment: Given that the data is supplied by a webapi server is there a simple way to  change the name of the properties when the data arrives (and change it back before amendments are posted to the server)

Comment: Thank you very much @michael-rose, that has worked a treat, I added a service to change property names based on an array of replacements: see my 'answer' (not enough space to post the service as a comment)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from @michael-rose I added a service that transforms the data on receipt from the webapi:

```
var DataClenseService = function () {
"use strict";
this.renameFields = function (data, fieldRenames) {
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (typeof data !== 'object') {
        return data;
    }
    var service = this;
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function (propertyName) {
        var matchingRenames = fieldRenames.filter(function (rename) { return rename.old === propertyName; });
        var currentValue = data[propertyName];
        if (matchingRenames.length == 1) {
            delete data[propertyName];
            data[matchingRenames[0].new] = service.renameFields(currentValue, fieldRenames);
        } else {
            data[propertyName] = service.renameFields(currentValue, fieldRenames);
        }
    });
    return data;
};
```

};

and simply call this as so:

```
var cleanedData = DataClenseService.renameFields(data, [{ old: '$values', new: 'values' }, { old: '$type', new: 'type' }]);
```